# What is the fallacy regarding knowing someone who is X therefore you know about topics regarding X?

Tags: fallacies

What is the name of the fallacy that goes along the lines of:

> My brother is a doctor so I know about medicine.

Comment: It should be an appeal to authority (in this specific case borrowed, or by association).

Comment: @Bread That looks like an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Maybe, but it's probably a duplicate question anyway. It was more a suggestion than an answer, since I'm not that sure about it. I'm surprised someone hasn't already either voted to close or given a real answer by now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What fallacy assumes that being familiar with something makes one an expert on it?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/29766/what-fallacy-assumes-that-being-familiar-with-something-makes-one-an-expert-on-i)

Comment: There's a question already on record with the answer "appeals to (irrelevant) authority". It also refers to "authority by association" (what I said above): What fallacy assumes that being *familiar* [e.g. "my brother"] with something makes one an expert on it?

Answer (score 1):

Because one's brother is a doctor does not make one a medical expert. To claim one is without having the actual expertise could be viewed as an argument from false authority.

[Bo Bennett](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/231/Argument-from-False-Authority) describes this fallacy as:

> When a person making a claim is presented as an expert who should be trusted when his or her expertise is not in the area being discussed.

As Bread suggests in a comment this is similar to another question although the artificial intelligence scenario presented in the other question may make this different enough for a separate answer: [What fallacy assumes that being familiar with something makes one an expert on it?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/29766/29944)

---

Bennett, B. Argument from False Authority. Retrieved on May 15, 2019 from *Logically Fallacious* at https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/231/Argument-from-False-Authority